# Assembly asm x86 Encryption/Decryption Program

Tags: c++, assembly, encryption

I've been creating this program for a while now and I can't work out how to solve the decryption routine, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The encryption part of the code works correctly as of now.

```
#include <conio.h>      // for kbhit
#include <iostream>     // for cin >> and cout <<
#include <iomanip>      // for fancy output
using namespace std;

#define MAXCHARS 6      // feel free to alter this, but 6 is the minimum
#define dollarchar '$'  // string terminator

char OChars[MAXCHARS],
     EChars[MAXCHARS],
     DChars[MAXCHARS] = "Soon!";    // Global Original, Encrypted, Decrypted character strings

//----------------------------- C++ Functions ----------------------------------------------------------

void get_char (char& a_character)
{
    cin >> a_character;
    while (((a_character < '0') | (a_character > 'z')) && (a_character != dollarchar))
    {   cout << "Alphanumeric characters only, please try again > ";
        cin >> a_character;
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void get_original_chars (int& length)
{   char next_char;
    length = 0;
    get_char (next_char);

    while ((length < MAXCHARS) && (next_char != dollarchar))
    {
        OChars [length++] = next_char;
        get_char (next_char);
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------- ENCRYPTION ROUTINES -------------------------------------------------------------------------

void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{   char temp_char;                     // char temporary store

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    // encrypt characters one at a time
    {
        temp_char = OChars [i];         //
        __asm {                         //
            push   eax                  // save register values on stack to be safe
            push   ecx                  // Push last parameter first 
            lea    eax,EKey 
            push   temp_char
            push   eax
            call   encrypt3             // encrypt the character
            mov    temp_char, al

            add    esp, 8                   // Clean parameters from stack

            pop    ecx                  // restore original register values from stack
            pop    eax                  //
        }
        EChars [i] = temp_char;         // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array
    }
   return;



   __asm {

   encrypt3: 
        push ebp                    // Save the old base pointer value
        mov ebp, esp                // Set the new base pointer value

        push edx                    // Save EDX to the first unused empty stack
        push ecx                    //ecx register containing the temp_char is pushed to the stack
        push eax                    // Save EAX to the first unused empty stack
        mov edx, [ebp + 8]          // Accessing the last value of ebp
        movzx eax, byte ptr[eax]    // Move 4 bytes to the EAX register
        rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
        rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
        rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
        mov edx, eax                // Move 4 bytes from EAX into edx
        pop eax                     // Restore original EAX
        mov byte ptr[eax], dl       //moves the Ekey value into the EAX register as an 8-bit value
        pop ecx                     //stores the current letter being encrypted within the ECX register (it was pushed to the stack earlier in the assembly code).
        xor ecx, edx                //clears the EDX register of all values
        mov eax, ecx                // Move 4 bytes from ECX into EAX
        ror al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
        ror al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
        ror al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
        pop edx                     // Restore the value of EDX
        pop ebx                     // Restore original EBX
        mov esp, ebp                // Dellocate local variables
        pop ebp                     // Restore the original value of EBP
        ret                         // Return EAX value





    }

    //--- End of Assembly code
}
// end of encrypt_chars function
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------- DECRYPTION ROUTINES -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
void decrypt_chars(int length, char EKey)
{

    return;

}
// end of decrypt_chars function
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So why do you *need* inline assembly code?  The rule of thumb is to get the algorithm working in a high level language, then only and only if necessary convert to assembly language (after reviewing the compiler's assembly language output).

Comment: Why do you use `rol al, 1` three times instead or `rol al, 3`?  You have no other instructions between them.  Is this supposed to be a rotate left with carry or an arithmetic shift left (which doesn't rotate the bits around).

Comment: You assembly language comments suck and are not descriptive of why you are using the instructions.  Yes, the `ror al, 1` instruction rotates one position to the *right* (comment is wrong).  But why are you rotating in the first place?  That is what needs to be answered by the comments.

Comment: We were already provided the base encryption code from our tutors in this fomat sorry my comments are just basic at the moment and are a work in progress until I complete the decryption routine

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, the choice of `rol al, 1` three times may be an instruction set constraint; baseline 8086 assembly only permits either an immediate `1` or register `cl` for shift counts.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, write your code in high language before placing into assembly language.

Here are some reasons:

### Clobbering `edx` register

```
mov edx, [ebp + 8]          // Accessing the last value of ebp
movzx eax, byte ptr[eax]    // Move 4 bytes to the EAX register
rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
mov edx, eax                // Move 4 bytes from EAX into edx
```

In the code above, you move `[ebp + 8]` into `edx`.  Then you copy `eax` into `edx` four instructions later.  Why bother with the first instruction here?

### Duplicate instructions

One of the common reasons for coding in assembly language is efficiency.  Supposedly you can code better than the compiler or use special instructions better than the compiler. You don't, as this example shows:

```
rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
rol al, 1                   // Rotate AL register one position to the left
```

The above should be coded as `rol al, 3`.
Also, is there a reason you are using `al` register instead of `eax`?

Clearing `edx` register is wrong
The operation does not match the comments.

```
   xor ecx, edx                //clears the EDX register of all values
```

The `edx` register is on the wrong side.
The statement `xor edx, edx` actually clears the `edx` register.

### Restart with high level language.

I suggest trashing your assembly language and rewriting the functions in a high level language.  Get it working first.  Examine the compiler's assembly language.  If you can code the algorithm more effectively than the compiler, then do so.

Comment: `rol al` and `rol eax` are not interchangeable. Since he operates on 8 bit characters, `al` is correct.